# How can i find the fastest path between two points if we change speeds in different quadrants?

Tags: geometry, functions, euclidean-geometry

The question itself is simple, but i saw it on a test and i didn't figure it out, i would be glad if someone game a hint:

The question goes as follows: We have two dots in 2 dimensional space, for example K(3,-5) and C(5,-2) what is the fastest time we can go from point K to point C if in quadrants I and II we have v1 = 5, and in quadrants III and IV we have v2 = 8;

My input:

First, when i saw this problem i though it was easy, because we use the formula for a equation of a section between two lines and we get the exact dot where we pass through the x coordinate and we calculate the different speeds in the two different quadrants and we add them together, but i quickly figured out that a straight line is not always the fastest path between two dots if we differ in speed.

Can we do it if we get the worst case (a straight line) and we iterate to the right of it, because we know that if we go to the left of it it will take more time,so we get the worst case and we go through all the points till we reach a better time, that the next point is worst, sooo something like point(x,0)>point(x+1,0), so the best time is point(x,0) and then we do the time calculation.

Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up "Snell's Law" and "The principle of least time."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Dosen't "The principle of least time" actually boil down to the "Snell's Law" which if i am correct uses a refractive index which i have no idea how to use here, since i am not give such an index. I also saw that there is a T (time required for the light to travel from point Q through point O to point P) but i cant find the fastest path with this formula (or at least i can't) i was trying with K(3 ,-20) and C( 3 ,25)  and v1=40 v2= 5 if you could give me an ex. how to substitute these into the formula. Since the answer here would be 5,5 and i cant get that with that formula.

Comment: The index of refraction is determined by the velocity $v$ by $n = c/v$.  Your choice of $c$ is irrelevant, so just set it to $1$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry but i just don't get it even when i substitute n1=1/40 and n2 = 1/5 i don't get how i can get the fastest time from point K to point C if you have time and energy, please show me with an example, because i when i use it i don't get the fastest time to be t=t1+t2 = 5,50000 (which it should be, in the reference above)

Comment: Actually when substitute in T i get the correct minimal time, but i cant figure out how to minimize it. Or it is just T that minimized speed, because when i get to sin(theta)/v1 -sin(theta)/v2 = 0 it actually doesn't equal that it and i cant figure out how to minimize it.

Comment: For example K(5,-3) C(-4,6) and have v1 = 2 (III and IV- speed) v2=5 (I and II -speed) if i let T be the time required for the light to travel from point K through point O to point C i get the time between these two dots to be close to 4.34...because it passes through O, but there is actually a faster path that goes straight up and then across. How do i get the fastest path because it the actual fastest path will be K->F(0,5)->C. How do i get that...

Comment: Write the time as function of x (the border where the velocity change). Use derivative to calculate the x for minimum. Plug in the equation for time.

Comment: But where do we change velocities, we actually don't know which is fastest path, and again, shortest path doesn't mean fastest, because of the different speeds, basically it boils down to we have to stay less time in the slower quadrants and more time in the faster quadrants, but how do we get the exact fast speed i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $K$ is in quadrant III or IV and $C$ is in quadrant I or II.
Let $P$ be a point on the $x$ axis with coordinates $(x,0).$

Given the coordinates of $K$, find an expression for the distance $KP$ in terms of $x.$ Find an expression for $t_{KP},$ the time to travel in a straight line from $K$ to $P$, in terms of $x.$

Given the coordinates of $C$, find an expression for the distance $PC$ in terms of $x.$ Find an expression for $t_{PC},$ the time to travel in a straight line from $P$ to $C$, in terms of $x.$

Then the total travel time from $K$ through $P$ to $C$ is $t_{KP}+t_{PC}.$
But you can write $t_{KP}+t_{PC}$ as a function of $x.$
Call this function $T(x)$.

Find the minimum value of $T(x).$
That is literally the value of $x$ that gives you the shortest time $T(x)$ to travel from $K$ to $C.$

Comment: Yes that is true if we didn't have time, when we have time, we need to understand, that we need to spend less time where the v is slower and more time where the v is faster, therefore the fastest time won't be a straight line. "The principle of least time"

Comment: @Peter What do you think $T(x) = t_{KP}+t_{PC}$ is? It is **time**. This answer is all about the fastest **time**. And it asks you to consider all possible points on the $x$ axis, not just the point on the straight line between $K$ and $C.$ In general the minimum $T(x)$ will occur at a point $(x,0)$ that is not on the straight line between $K$ and $C.$